# Laravel - Sum values on the same date query builder then "combine" all same date into only 1 row

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel, query-builder

Consider:

```
$tglA = $request->tglA;
$tglB = $request->tglB;
$group = $request->group;
$barangId = $request->barangId;
$kodeMerk = $request->kodeMerk;
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$tglTotal = new DatePeriod($tglA, $interval, $tglB);
if($group == 'true') {
    if(empty($request->departemenId)) {
        $scoreboard = HistoryPenjualan::select('kodeSales', 'departemenId', DB::raw('SUM(score) as totalScore'))
            ->whereBetween('tgl', [$tglA, $tglB])
            ->groupBy('departemenId')
            ->orderBy('totalScore', 'desc')
            ->get();
    }
```

How can I sum the score value of the same date of whereBetween date range and then not show the duplicated date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to `GROUP BY DATE(tgl)`:

```
$scoreboard = HistoryPenjualan::select('kodeSales', 'departemenId', DB::raw('SUM(score) as totalScore'))
    ->whereBetween('tgl', [$tglA, $tglB])
    ->groupBy('departemenId', DB::raw('DATE(tgl)'))
    ->orderBy('totalScore', 'desc')
    ->get();
```